# purpose of variable annotation in python

Tags: python, annotations

Trying to understand the rationale for using annotations in python. I have come across code that looks like this

```
import logging
logger: logging.Logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def example(a,b):
    return a+b

if __name__ == '__main__':
    example()
```

vs

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

and I am confused as to why do this. I have read the documentation that states the purpose of the `:` is to annotate and notify the receiving variable what type it is going to be. but shouldn't setting it with `=` do the same thing?

Is there a performance reason for this? a cleaner way to write code? what is the function of annotating a variable like this?

edit:

I understand the purpose of annotation when requesting inputs as in the following code as this prevents errors in regards to typing from input error:

```
def carl(word: str = None):
     return(word + "is a pickle:)
```

edit: changed example due to comments

Comment: This annotation is simply wrong.

Comment: Does it have to do with more complex class outputs? like panda dataframes or specialized classes? As in annotating for these more complex structures to ensure no errors with overriding variables later down the road?

Comment: To expand on Matthias comment: In some sense, variable annotations mean whatever the person who wrote the code *wants* them to mean. However, PEP-526 introduced them as a complement to function annotations specifically to increase support for type hints. PEP-563 officially deprecates the use of any annotations that aren't in support of type hinting as defined by PEP-484 and other later PEPs.

Comment: Specifically, `bobby.add_bob` is not a type in any sense currently defined by any type-related PEPs.

Comment: And as annotations of *any* kind are purely optional, it should not and does not affect the runtime semantics of the code.

Comment: understood. Annotation is an aid for developers. Thanks for the information

Comment: And it is used by some editors/linters to check the code.